# How to hide one text and display another when both are in same position for CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out how to use hover to have one text hide and another be displayed in its place when you hover over in its area. I've tried 2 different methods and these two don't seem to work:

```
<div id = "Area">
<span id="name">big-name-1234156</span>
<span id="name2">small-name</span>
</div>

#name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#name2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#Area:hover .name {
  opacity: 0;
}

#Area:hover .name2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#name:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

#name:hover #name2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

How can I hide 'name' and display 'name2' when I hover over the text when they are both in the same position? I just don't know what I am doing wrong here or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better make the container `relative` if it has `absolute` elements within. also better keep one *not* absolute so it will take up the space of the flow.

You may add transition for a less dramatic effect.

```css
#Area {
  position:relative; 
}

#name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#name2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#Area:hover #name {
  opacity: 0;
}

#Area:hover #name2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
before
<div id="Area">
  <span id="name">big-name-1234156</span>
  <span id="name2">small-name</span>
</div>
after
```